# Check if jQuery object has html element in it

Tags: jquery, dom

Maybe I miss something but anywhere I read it is suggested that if I want to check whether a jQuery constructor returns a jQuery object is done by:

`if(jQuery('.something').length){...}`

but how would I validate if it is an html element in the jQuery object that it returns?

what I mean is that this also returns true:

`if(jQuery(44551).length){...}`

although it returns jQuery object it doesn't have html element in it.

Comment: jQuery's selectors return only HTML elements.

Comment: but what if I provide a number to the jQuery constructor, it won't return html element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) to check if the collection contains an element matching a certain selector

```
var someelement = $(....); // unknown

if ( someelement.is('.something') ) {...
```

> Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element,
>   or jQuery object and return true if at least one of these elements
>   matches the given arguments.

Comment: ok that solves my problem. `$('.never-mind').is('.never-mind')` returns true (of course after validating that .never-mind exists), and `$(555).is(555)` returns false. thank you mate

Answer (score 0):

To check if there are html elements inside a jQuery element, then do:

```
if ( $('.el').html().length ) { ...
```

Comment: if I provide a number to the jQuery selector your code throws an error, I could wrap it in a try-catch statement, but @adeneo's solution is simpler. thanks though.